# Match object keys with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents containing a field like so:

```
...
placements: [
    "<id0>",
    "<id1>",
    "<id2>"
]
...
```

In order to get all documents for which placements contains id0, I can do:

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "term" : { "placements" : "<id0>"}
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need to change this array to an object, in order to map ids to a state (string):

```
...
placements: {
    "<id0>": "active",
    "<id1>": "active",
    "<id2>": "paused"
}
...
```

I would like to knwo if there is a way to still be able to check if a given id is one o the keys of the placements object ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the [exists filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html) is what you're looking for.

I created an index and added two docs, one that has the `"<id2>"` property and one that doesn't:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/1" -d'
{
   "name": "doc1",
   "placements": {
      "<id0>": "active",
      "<id1>": "active",
      "<id2>": "paused"
   }
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/docs/2" -d'
{
   "name": "doc2",
   "placements": {
      "<id0>": "paused",
      "<id1>": "active"
   }
}'
```

and then I can query with the `"exists"` filter:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "exists": {
               "field": "<id2>"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

and I get back the right result:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "docs",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "doc1",
               "placements": {
                  "<id0>": "active",
                  "<id1>": "active",
                  "<id2>": "paused"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is a runnable example you can play with:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/e727360fc472a9c0a6a2a1cf7050d1b42f6cd773